# How to resolve out of memory error when converting bitmap to Base64 string format and vice versa?

Tags: android, bitmap, base64

I need to upload some captured images to a .net webserver using SOAP request. Since SOAP accepts strings for image files also, I am converting captured image files into string using `android.util.Base64 class`.

But when converting image files into strings using Base64 encoding format, I am getting an out of memory error.

How can I resolve the out of memory error when converting image files into Base64 format strings?

Comment: I think step 1 here is to get a memory profiler.

Answer (score 4):

I think Ben is saying for you to chop up your bitmap and encode each chunk separately. On the other end, you'll have to reconstruct the byte array with the multiple base64 chunks. Each chunk should be ordered and probably best to include the final size of the byte array so that the receiver knows what size to allocate.

something like:

```
byte[] bitmap = byte[size];
int j = 1;
write to xml stream: final size = size
for (i=0; i&lt;size; i+chunkSize) {
    write to xml stream: base64.encode(bitmap from i to i+chunkSize)
    write to xml stream: order = j++
}
```

I wouldn't rely on the order to be strictly how it is written to the xml stream in case your receiver canonicalizes your xml.

Answer (score 0):

Can you read each image file in chunks, convert those, appending them to a file as you go, and then read that file back out in chunks when sending?

Comment: Hi Ben, Thanks for your quick replay. The thing is i am capturing image  using camera and getting that image file as bitmap and converting it into byte[] and passing this array to android.util.Base64.encodeToString() method as parameter which will converts the image and return a Base64 format string. there i am getting out of memory error. Could you please solve with an example?

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the code you're using, please?

Answer (score 0):

Decoding to Bitmap would mean more memory foot print. Specially its a big waste if you just want to convert from JPEG to Base64.

In most of the answers I have seen they convert it as JPEG > BITMAP > Byte[] > Base64.
Most of the memory exception happens when you decode a big jpeg to bitmap.

I am still looking for a good solution but check this answer out. He is converting file byte array to Base64 directly.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10160856/499752