# How do I decode a jpeg image encoded in Base64 in android and see it on an ImageView?

Tags: android, arrays, base64, jpeg, itemizedoverlay

My server sends a encoded Base64 string to my android device. After that, I decode the Base64 string in this method to make a drawable of it. I can't see the image when I add it in an Itemizedoverlay.

```
public Drawable seticon(String input){

    byte[] b = Base64.decode(input, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);
    Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(decodedByte);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, 50, 50);
    return drawable;
}

public void setphotopoint(String input){
    Drawable drawable = seticon(input);
    PhotoOverlay aPhotoOverlay = new PhotoOverlay(drawable, this);
    OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem();
    overlayitem.setMarker(drawable);
    aPhotoOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
    overlays.add(aPhotoOverlay);
}
```

this is my PhotoOverlay class

```
public class PhotoOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>{

    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> items = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

    Context mContext ;

    public PhotoOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
        this.mContext = context;
    }
    public PhotoOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    protected boolean onTap(int index) {
        return true;
    }

    public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
        items.add(overlay);
        //setLastFocusedIndex(-1);
        populate();
    }
    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return items.get(i);
    }
    public void clear() {
        items.clear();
        populate();
    }

    public void removeOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
        items.remove(overlay);
        populate();
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return items.size();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert your binary file to Base64 then use the following code to retrieve it:

```
public static void base64ToFile(String path, String strBase64)
            throws IOException {
        byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(strBase64);
        byteArrayTofile(path, bytes);
    }

public static void byteArrayTofile(String path, byte[] bytes)
        throws IOException {
    File imagefile = new File(path);
    File dir = new File(imagefile.getParent());
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
    }
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(imagefile);
    fos.write(bytes);
    fos.close();
}
```

---

converting binary file to Base64:

```
public static String fileToBase64(String path) throws IOException {
    byte[] bytes = fileToByteArray(path);
    return Base64.encodeBytes(bytes);
}

public static byte[] fileToByteArray(String path) throws IOException {
    File imagefile = new File(path);
    byte[] data = new byte[(int) imagefile.length()];
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(imagefile);
    fis.read(data);
    fis.close();
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Converting binary to Base64, does this mean that I can convert a jpeg to binary >> Base64 without converting to bitmap? If so this is brilliant!