# How to encode JPEG / PNG to Base64 without decoding to bitmap, using less memory

Tags: android, memory-management, bitmap, base64

There are good resource over converting JPEG to base64.

I am particularly interested in doing it **without decoding to bimap, avoiding any memory inflation.** I also understand that any file can be encoded into Base64 by converting it into byte array first.

So if we can directly create a byte array of JPEG / PNG file which is far less than the byte array of a decoded jpeg bitmap we can convert it to base64 using less memory footprint.

The closest answer I have come across is this https://stackoverflow.com/a/10160856/499752

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64OutputStream.html

Answer (score 0):

```
public void getGalleryDetails(String path) throws FileNotFoundException {


    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(path);
    byte[] bytes;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    int bytesRead;
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try{
        while((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1){
            output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    bytes = output.toByteArray();

    encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Log.i("ENCODED", encodedImage);
}
```

You could actually use this ... where you can provide the path of the file to be converted to Base64. Sorry for the late post ... Just say this post.